# Find all *.sh files in directory

Tags: shell, for-loop, directory

I want to find all *.sh files in some directory, but there are some errors in the script...

```
#!/bin/sh
for plik in /var/panel/starter/*
do  
    if [ $(basename "$plik") != "priority" ] && [ $(basename "$plik") != "PRIORITY" ] 
    then
    for plik in $plik/*
    do
        filename=$(basename "$plik")
        extension="${filename##*.}"
        filename="${filename%.*}"
        if [ "$extension" == "sh" ]
        then
        echo $plik
        fi
    done
    fi
done
```

There are some folders in /var/panel/starter, and in these folders there are shell scripts that's why I used for loop twice.

This is the error:

```
[: 19: *: unexpected operator
[: 19: sh: unexpected operator
[: 19: sh: unexpected operator
[: 19: sh: unexpected operator
[: 19: *: unexpected operator
```

I guess the problem is with empty folders like:

```
/var/panel/starter/cs16/*
```

and I don't have an idea how to deal with that.

Comment: can you just `find -name "*.sh"` ? if you want to do some filter you could use `-regex` or pipe the output to `grep`. or I misunderstood your requirement

Comment: `/var/panel/starter/*.sh`?

Comment: It was only an example. Later I want to execute that scripts. Instead of echo $plik it will be sh $plik. Without `if [ "$extension" == "sh" ]` condition it would execute also `/var/panel/starter/cs16/*` and I'm trying to avoid that. 
@devnull, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sh: unexpected operator` should give you a clue.

You are executing your script using `sh` which doesn't support the `==` operator on line 19.  Executing your script using `bash` should work fine, or just use `=`.

Answer (score 21):

Why to use a script, when you can achieve the same using :

```
find path_to_folder -iname "*.sh"
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use find and grep?

```
find /var/panel/starter/ -name "*.sh" | grep -iv "/var/panel/starter/priority"
```